# Send keys from an electron application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, keyboard, electron

The only thing I can find related to this is [sendInputEvent](https://electronjs.org/docs/all#contentssendinputeventevent).

There's a couple problems with it.

1. It seems that it can only be called from the main window thread. I need this to happen when someone clicks a button in the application.
2. It doesn't even seem to work at all even from the main window thread. Example, this doesn't seem to do anything:

code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    win.webContents.sendInputEvent({keyCode: 'Tab', type: 'keyDown', modifiers: ['alt']});
}, 3000);
```

3. I want to send some key strokes *after* the alt-tab as well, and the API says that the function only works if the window is focused.

It looks like RobotJS *might* work for this, but it seems a bit heavy-handed for something that is one line in other languages (e.g. `SendKeys.Send`). Also it looks like it requires building it manually. All in all I'm trying to keep my absolute dependency count to a minimum if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I agree RobotJS is a beast for that task and instead I would go for [node-key-sender](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-key-sender)

I would also not send the `ALT-TAB` keystroke and instead would use `window.hide()` or `window.minimize`. You can read more here: [Electron API docs for minimize() and hide()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winminimize)

It has all the features you need and would work even after you unfocus from your electron window. The only caveat is that it uses Java Runtime behind the scenes